# regexp, help with assertions

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
<a name="subhd_182"></a>
<a name="st_394"></a>
<a name="st_395"></a>
<a name="qn_494"></a>
<a name="st_495"></a>
<a name="qn_594"></a>
<a name="st_595"></a>

<a name="subhd_282"></a>
<a name="qn_694"></a>
<a name="st_695"></a>
<a name="qn_794"></a>
<a name="st_795"></a>
<a name="qn_894"></a>
<a name="st_895"></a>`
```

And I want to replace every `<a name="st_\d*"></a>` with `<a name="qn_\d*"></a>` if it follows immediately `<a name="subhd_\d*"></a>`

I use this regex `%(.*<a name="subhd_.*)(?=<a name="st(?!<a name="qn))(<a name=")st(.*)%sU` and replace with `$1$2qn$3`. But it also replaces second case too

Comment: i don't know why i haven't accepted any of answers before, i think there were some qualification, which i haven't posted, but as long as both answers working, as i tested them just now, i'm accepting one and upvoting both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you only want to match name after the first subhd row above, but not the second, since the first one is an "st_" and the second one is a "qn_".

Try:

```
(<a name="subhd_\d+">\s*<\/a>\s*<a name=")st(_\d+">)
```

where you would replace as `$1qn$2`  Note that here I have assumed that you were quite literal when you said "it follows immediately .

I don't really understand why you're throwing the lookahead in, unless the actual rule you're trying to implement is more complicated than you've stated.

Answer (score 1):

Try: `%(<a name="subhd_\d+"></a>\n<a name=")st(.*)%sU` and replace with `$1qn$2`. On a sidenote I don't really know what the U modifier does for you here. Also, you might want to change your `\n` newline matcher according to your operating system.

I have found [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) a really useful tool for regular expressions.